# What's an Agnostic Service

Tags: soa

I'm reading about SOA principals and patterns, but I can not understand what is an agnostic service. Do you have any straight forward definition of it? What is the concept and usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A nice explanation can be found in  [Agnostic/non-agnostic revisited](http://soa-ind.blogspot.com/2011/02/agnosticnon-agnostic-revisited.html) :

> (i) agnostic services are **not aware of the context in which they are being called**, nor are they aware of how the service is implemented, which platform, technology etc.
>
> (ii) non-agnostic services **can have one or more forms of coupling or context** (ie. process functional context).

Answer (score 5):

An Agnostic service is generic in nature / its independent of context.
A Service something that is generalized so that it is interoperable among various systems.

An autonomous service which is self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

I think it means implementing services that can be used by any language that can make an HTTP request to it.  The implementation language can be your choice - Java, .NET, Python, or anything else.  Same for clients.

Answer (score 0):

furthermore,Agnostic service has parametric in nature.